# php xpath find all alike nodes

Tags: php, xpath

I am using php xpath and trying to get all nodes with in my xml that begin with scp:custom_label

my xml is:

```
<entry>
    <scp:availability>in stock</scp:availability>
    <scp:price unit='USD'>8.99</scp:price>
    <scp:custom_label_0>seasonal</scp:custom_label_0>
    <scp:custom_label_1>clearance</scp:custom_label_1>
    <scp:custom_label_2>holiday</scp:custom_label_2>
    <scp:custom_label_3>sale</scp:custom_label_3>
    <scp:custom_label_4>best seller</scp:custom_label_4>
</entry>
```

I tried using:

```
$numEntries = $entry->getXpath()->query("//*[contains(.,'scp:custom_label')]")->length;
```

I am not getting any results back

I would like to see that $numEntries is equal to 5.

I appreciate the help. Thank you very much

Comment: Your XML specification is bad; `<custom_label>` should be the tag with multiple elements inside.

Answer (score 2):

Use `local-name()` for this

```
$res = $xpath->query("//*[contains(local-name(),'custom_label')]");
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and your answer. It got me on the right path

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$xpath->query("//*[contains(local-name(),'custom_label')]");
```

thank you tlenss

Comment: It would be better if you accepted the other answer, since most of this came directly from it.